# Post on user behalf on Facebook with Java

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-social

Is it possible that my FB app to post on users behalf without any interaction from the user (server-side). I suspect that an initial login and request permission phase is needed, but after that I want that my app to post on their behalf for, let's say, the next month.

I'm using Java and I'm leaning towards Spring Social, but any similar framework is acceptable.

I know that this question has been asked, but I don't think with Spring Social.

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter` ([see API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/connect/FacebookAdapter.html)) has an `updateStatus` method which takes a `FaceBook` and a `String`.  Looks like it would do the trick.

`FaceBook` itself is instantiated by first acquiring an access token from facebook, and then passing the token as a String to FaceBookTemplate's constructor, like so (copied from [Spring's reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/apis.html)):

```
String accessToken = "f8FX29g..."; // access token received from Facebook after OAuth authorization
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
```

I believe you could use Quartz to schedule and execute the task itself.

Comment: But how do I get the `accessToken`? For posting the message I can also use `FeedOperations`.

Comment: You can use the `ConnectController`.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ConnectController.html